# PHP7 with google API

Tags: php, composer-php, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to start new PHP project with google api (calendar). I'm trying to install api using composer. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or it's not support php7

**Command:**

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC
```

**Result:**

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\kalendar>composer require
google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC ./composer.json has been updated Loading 
composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies
(including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an
installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package google/apiclient 2.0.0@RC exists as google/apiclient
[1.0.2-beta, 1.0.3-beta, 1.0.4-beta, 1.0.5-beta, 1.0.6-beta, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3
, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, dev-add-callback-cache, dev-add-psr6, dev-master,
2.x-dev, dev-v1-master, v1.0.0-alpha, v1.0.1-beta, v2.0.0-RC1, v2.0.0-RC2, v2.0.
0-RC3, v2.0.0-RC4, v2.0.0-RC5, v2.0.0-RC6, v2.0.0-RC7] but these are rejected by
 your constraint.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by executing composer with exact version

```
composer require v2.0.0-RC7
```